# .htaccess 301 remove folder by position

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to set up some 301 redirects between links residing on the same domain. 
Native urls syntax is    **/product/XX/productname** or **/product/XXX/productname**
New urls syntax will be  **/product/productname**

the "XX" position stands for a two or three digits variable number that I need to get rid of.

What rewrite rule can I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(product)/...?/(.+)/?$ /$1/$2/
```

Comment: Many thanks, I've tried but didn't work, here is my .htaccess located in the subfolder that contains "product". 

Am I missing something?

RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(product)/..?/(.+)/?$ /$1/$2

Comment: What is the sub directory name? Does it already have a .htaccess? If yes then make sure this rule is very first rule there.

Comment: The subdirectory name is "test", it didn't have an .htaccess before but the root site has it (it is the one generated by default from wordpress installation) could this be the problem?

Comment: And what is full URL that you're trying change? Does it really start with `/product/` or something else?

Comment: Two examples:

www.mydomain.com/product/xx/id1 to www.mydomain.com/product/id1/   
www.mydomain.com/product/xxx/id2 to www.mydomain.com/product/id2/
please note, the old site is a normal php site, the new one is based on Wordpress.
Also, the new links will end with a slash because of Wordpress configuration...

Comment: Ok see the updated code and **make sure to place it as first line in main WP .htaccess file (not in sib directory)**